# Wordpress most flexible format for dates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a library called Custom Metaboxes and Fields for Wordpress to add meta data to my custom post types. It's an event website.

I had it all going, but started to have issues with sorting when trying to filter the `adjacent_post_links` from singe posts.

I figured it might be that I am storing the date in m/d/y and not Y/m/d.

So, i've started over trying to work with a UNIX date timestamp as I have read this is the way to go. Now, I am having issues with my custom `wp_queries` pulling my filtered posts on the front page. I think it has to do with needing to work with timezones.

Anyways, over the long run, what are the best practices in storing date in mysql? I've also been reading about using `STR_TO_Date()` to properly format date so that you can order and compare dates if needed. Would this be an option if I went back to dates being stored in m/d/y .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store  dates as Unix timestamps in the database, it 'll gives you lots of trouble because it is not easily readable.for Example(unix format): '1410738238'

if you store as datetime format in the database, it is easy readable efficient and very flexiable,also mysql provides a lot of date functions.for Example(datetime format): '1970-01-01 00:00:01'

for more information  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For whatever reason the library I am using only stores things as Unix timestamps.